# user32 AnimateWindow Function not sliding the correct form

Tags: c#, user32

I am trying to add a window slide to one of my subforms. I will give a brief rundown of what this small part does in my app.

User types in a range of IP Address. App does all the pinging and displays the results in a new form (dynamicly).

Here is how I want it to work: If the user runs the ping once, nothing will happen in regards to the slide animation. But if the user clicks the "Retry" control on the results form, the new results window will slid out from the right of the old results form.

On the results form (Named: Ping_Form) I added the following into the load event:

```
[DllImport("user32")]
    static extern bool AnimateWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int time, int flags);
    //Constants
    const int AW_SLIDE = 0X40000;
    const int AW_HOR_POSITIVE = 0X1;
    const int AW_HOR_NEGATIVE = 0X2;
    const int AW_BLEND = 0X80000;


 void ping_Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
        bool is_Open = false;

        FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
        foreach (Form f in fc)
            {
            if (f.Name == "PSE")
                is_Open = true;
            }
        if (is_Open == false)
            return;
        //Load the Form At Position of Main Form
        int WidthOfMain = Application.OpenForms["PSE"].Width;
        int HeightofMain = Application.OpenForms["PSE"].Height;
        int LocationMainX = Application.OpenForms["PSE"].Location.X;
        int locationMainy = Application.OpenForms["PSE"].Location.Y;

        //Set the Location


        this.Location = new Point(LocationMainX + WidthOfMain, locationMainy + 10);

        //Animate form
        AnimateWindow(this.Handle, 500, AW_SLIDE | AW_HOR_POSITIVE);


        }
```

But when I run the ping method, a blank form is created and slides out, but the results form just appears normal.

Any director or advice would be great in this area. Thanks so much!

Comment: If anyone needs anymore code for context, let me know and I will post more.. This app is around 1500 Lines, so don't want to post the whole thing since most would be unrelated to this questing.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this.Show(); after your call to AnimateWindow.

Comment: I tried adding this.show() but it doesn't do anything...I fee the problem lies in the form_Load event...Any ideas?